# What is the best way to install graphic card drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

I have a 64bit laptop with two grapgic cards (and one of them is Nvidia). In application Additional Drivers there was nothing under the tab "Additional drivers".

So I wondered - should I download GPU drivers from the official nvidia site or maybe by `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` because the seemed pretty different. Or maybe somehow else?

Answer (score 1):

You could download the NVIDIA Driver x64 version from here. http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/77525/en-us. You will actually be downloading .run file. After downloading the file, you will have to open terminal and follow these steps:

1. Make the .run file executable by typing `sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.32.run`
2. Then, type after the above executed, `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.32.run`

Now, you could proceed with the installation.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of Additional Drivers is a known bug in Ubuntu 14.04 (I'm guessing you're running that). I ran into this issue myself with my GTX 750 Ti.

Unless you need the performance boost for gaming, the default Nouveau drivers are just fine. However, if you do want the performance there are multiple methods to resolving this.

**Download & install via the .run file from NVIDIA.**

1. You'll need to download the newest NVIDIA stable driver from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/77525/en-us) and save it somewhere you'll remember - your home directory is a good choice.

   Note, make sure you've saved and closed all your applications before continuing any further, because you're going to kill the display manager/X server and thus any applications running.
2. Once the driver has downloaded, you'll need to go into a TTY. You can do this via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Once you've got a text console, you need to log in with your username and password.
3. Once you've logged in on the TTY you need to get the same directory as the downloaded .run file. It'll be in your downloads folder most likely. Run `cd ~/Downloads`.
4. Next, you'll need to kill the display manager/X server. You can accomplish this via running `sudo killall lightdm`.
5. Finally, run `sudo chmod +x ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.32.run && sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.32.run`.

   You'll have to accept a few things here and there. If you get an error saying that the pre-installation script failed, go ahead and ignore that. I got the exact same error and there's no actual problem.
6. Once the script completes, you'll need to run `sudo reboot` and you should boot into an NVIDIA-drivers-driven system!

**Use the Xorg-Edgers PPA Drivers**:

This seems to be the most common answer, but it's probably not the best choice, because the drivers from this PPA are known to cause various graphical issues like black screens and whatnot.

If the first method doesn't work, go ahead and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
sudo reboot
```

This will add the Xorg-Edgers PPA and install the latest NVIDIA 340 drivers. Once you reboot you can remove, or keep the PPA - that's up to you.

Comment: Everything seems okey but when I reboot the screen is black.

Comment: @Jantomedes Which solution did you follow? Because, if you followed the second, that is a danger that I warned against.

Comment: No, the first one. I'm thinking now of reinstalling all the system and thaen the first thing I'm gonna do is installing it this way. But I tried this once on another cumputer and it ended the same.

Comment: I also have some problems like not working `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`.

Comment: And when I start the system by rebooting computer I usually get a message that system is running in low-graphics mode but it shows also almost just black screen.

Comment: @Jantomedes Well, the `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` command not working is actually where the bug is. Since that command doesn't work, Additional Drivers doesn't have anything to go off of. Did you install any drivers in any form other than my first solution?

Comment: Well, at first I tried to install it using `apt-get install nvidia-current` and then I tried installing it from the file just a bit else way than yours (`init 3` instead of `chmod [...]`) and then I tried your one.

Comment: @Jantomedes Your running `apt-get install nvidia-current` could be what's causing this. Did you reboot after installing them?

Comment: I think so. Gimme an hour or two so I can reinstall system and download the driver.

Comment: after reinstalling the system and installing the driver from the file your way, I just end up with a black screen with one `_` character (not flashing) in the left upper corner. I cannot perform any action (like getting into tty1).

Comment: @Jantomedes Oh brother - drivers can be such a pain. Does the GRUB menu show during boot? If not, try pressing Shift during boot and see if you can boot in recovery mode and use the second method. While it's not what you want to do first off, it's quite often the only choice.